# How can I send column values as the payload in a postgresql NOTIFY message?

Tags: postgresql, notify, listen

If an entry in a table satisfies certain conditions, a NOTIFY is sent out. I want the payload to include the ID number and several other columns of information. Is there a postgres method to convert variables (OLD.ColumnID, etc) to strings?

using postgres 9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade Postgres to a version that supported JSON.

Answer (score 4):

@klin is correct that `NOTIFY` doesn't support anything other than string literals. However there is a function [pg_notify()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) which takes normal arguments to deal with exactly this situation. It's been around since at least 9.0 and that link is to the official documentation - always worth reading it carefully, there is a wealth of information there.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the notify has to be done within a trigger function. Use a dynamic query, e.g.

```
execute format('notify channel, ''id: %s''', old.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the long answer, i just cant walk away without reacting to the other answers too.

The `format` version fails in many ways. Before EXECUTE, you shoud prepare the plan. The "pseudo command"  does not fits the syntax of execute which is

```
EXECUTE somepreparedplanname (parameter1, ...)
```

The %s in format is again too bad, this way you can summon sql injection attacks. When constructing a query with `format`, you need to use %L for literals %I for column/table/function/etc ids, and use %s almost never.

The other solution with the `pg_notify` function is correct. Try

```
LISTEN channel;
SELECT pg_notify('channel','Id: '|| pg_backend_pid  ());
```

in psql command line.

So back to the original question: sdemurjian,
Its not clarified in the question, if you wants to use this notification thing in some trigger function. So here is an example (maybe not) for you (because im a little late. sorry for that too):

```
CREATE TABLE columns("columnID" oid, "columnData" text);
CREATE FUNCTION column_trigger_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$ BEGIN PERFORM pg_notify('columnchannel', 'Id: '||OLD."columnID");
RETURN NEW; END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER column_notify BEFORE UPDATE ON columns FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE column_trigger_func();
LISTEN columnchannel;
INSERT INTO columns VALUES(1,'testdata');
BEGIN; UPDATE columns SET "columnData" = 'success'; END;
BEGIN; UPDATE columns SET "columnData" = 'fail'; ROLLBACK;
```

Please note that in early postgres versions (any before 9), the notify command does not accepts any payload and there is no pg_notify function.

In 8.1 the trigger function stil works if you define it like

```
CREATE FUNCTION column_trigger_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$ BEGIN NOTIFY columnchannel; RETURN NEW; END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even postgresql 9.3 supports json. You could have just used `row_to_json(payload)::text`